# Growing matrices columnwise in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In pure Python you can grow matrices column by column pretty easily:

```
data = []
for i in something:
    newColumn = getColumnDataAsList(i)
    data.append(newColumn)
```

[NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)'s array doesn't have the append function. The `hstack` function doesn't work on zero sized arrays, thus the following won't work:

```
data = numpy.array([])
for i in something:
    newColumn = getColumnDataAsNumpyArray(i)
    data = numpy.hstack((data, newColumn)) # ValueError: arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

So, my options are either to remove the initalization iside the loop with appropriate condition:

```
data = None
for i in something:
    newColumn = getColumnDataAsNumpyArray(i)
    if data is None:
        data = newColumn
    else:
        data = numpy.hstack((data, newColumn)) # works
```

... or to use a Python list and convert is later to array:

```
data = []
for i in something:
    newColumn = getColumnDataAsNumpyArray(i)
    data.append(newColumn)
data = numpy.array(data)
```

Both variants seem a little bit awkward to be. Are there nicer solutions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

NumPy actually does have an *append* function, which it seems might do what you want, e.g.,

```
import numpy as NP
my_data = NP.random.random_integers(0, 9, 9).reshape(3, 3)
new_col = NP.array((5, 5, 5)).reshape(3, 1)
res = NP.append(my_data, new_col, axis=1)
```

your second snippet (hstack) will work if you add another line, e.g.,

```
my_data = NP.random.random_integers(0, 9, 16).reshape(4, 4)
# the line to add--does not depend on array dimensions
new_col = NP.zeros_like(my_data[:,-1]).reshape(-1, 1)
res = NP.hstack((my_data, new_col))
```

`hstack` gives the same result as `concatenate((my_data, new_col), axis=1)`, i'm not sure how they compare performance-wise.

---

While that's the most direct answer to your question, i should mention that looping through a data source to populate a target via *append*, while just fine in python, is not idiomatic NumPy. Here's why:

*initializing a NumPy array is relatively expensive*, and with this conventional python pattern, you incur that cost, more or less, at each loop iteration (i.e., each append to a NumPy array is roughly like initializing a new array with a different size).

For that reason, the common pattern in NumPy for iterative addition of columns to a 2D array is to initialize an empty target array *once*(or pre-allocate a single 2D NumPy array having all of the empty columns) the successively populate those empty columns by setting the desired column-wise offset (index)--much easier to show than to explain:

```
>>> # initialize your skeleton array using 'empty' for lowest-memory footprint 
>>> M = NP.empty(shape=(10, 5), dtype=float)

>>> # create a small function to mimic step-wise populating this empty 2D array:
>>> fnx = lambda v : NP.random.randint(0, 10, v)
```

populate NumPy array as in the OP, except each iteration just re-sets the values of M at successive column-wise offsets

```
>>> for index, itm in enumerate(range(5)):    
        M[:,index] = fnx(10)

>>> M
  array([[ 1.,  7.,  0.,  8.,  7.],
         [ 9.,  0.,  6.,  9.,  4.],
         [ 2.,  3.,  6.,  3.,  4.],
         [ 3.,  4.,  1.,  0.,  5.],
         [ 2.,  3.,  5.,  3.,  0.],
         [ 4.,  6.,  5.,  6.,  2.],
         [ 0.,  6.,  1.,  6.,  8.],
         [ 3.,  8.,  0.,  8.,  0.],
         [ 5.,  2.,  5.,  0.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  6.,  5.,  9.,  1.]])
```

of course if you don't known in advance what size your array should be
just create one much bigger than you need and trim the 'unused' portions
when you finish populating it

```
>>> M[:3,:3]
  array([[ 9.,  3.,  1.],
         [ 9.,  6.,  8.],
         [ 9.,  7.,  5.]])
```

Comment: Very helpful post for a numpy newbie. Quick question: is there any reason why you use

`for index, itm in enumerate(range(5)):`

rather than just, for example,

`for x in range(5):`

seeing as index and itm have the same value and only one is used.

Comment: @JohnBarça  thanks for the feedback. You might be right that the details of my code snippet should have been more carefully chosen--ie, in my example, the value of 'index' at every iteration is indeed the same as the value of the loop variable. That's an artifact though--the values of these two variables are likely to be not equal in practice (eg, the iterable is a list containing values to pass to a function which creates the 1D arrays which are then 'inserted' into the target array).

Answer (score 5):

Usually you don't keep resizing a NumPy array when you create it.  What don't you like about your third solution?  If it's a very large matrix/array, then it might be worth allocating the array before you start assigning its values:

```
x = len(something)
y = getColumnDataAsNumpyArray.someLengthProperty

data = numpy.zeros( (x,y) )
for i in something:
   data[i] = getColumnDataAsNumpyArray(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

The hstack can work on zero sized arrays:

```
import numpy as np

N = 5
M = 15

a = np.ndarray(shape = (N, 0))
for i in range(M):
    b = np.random.rand(N, 1)
    a = np.hstack((a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is expensive to keep reallocating the NumPy array - so your third solution is really the best performance wise.

However I think `hstack` will do what you want - the cue is in the error message,

> ## ValueError: arrays must have same number of dimensions`

I'm guessing that newColumn has two dimensions (rather than a 1D vector), so you need data to also have two dimensions..., for example, `data = np.array([[]])` - or alternatively make newColumn a 1D vector (generally if things are 1D it is better to keep them 1D in NumPy, so broadcasting, etc. work better). in which case use `np.squeeze(newColumn)` and `hstack` or `vstack` should work with your original definition of the data.