# Adding Features to Random Forests Classifier --- SciKit / Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am very new to `RFC` (random forests classifier) and I try to complete a fairly simple example.

I have a training dataset of 3 columns like below:

```
Utm_term  | DayOfWeek  | Customers
```

I have already set up a `RandomForest` model to train on the `Query` data (presented as texts) using the **Bag-of-words** method.

However, I cannot figure out how to add the `DayOfWeek` (presented as integers from 0 to 6) as an additional feature in the model. I have tried a few solutions from below but still I could not get there:

```
# Initialize the "CountVectorizer" object, which is scikit-learn's
# bag of words tool.  

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",
                         tokenizer = None,
                         preprocessor = None,
                         stop_words = None,
                         max_features = 5000) 

# The column I want to add as additional feature:
train_day = train["DayOfWeek"]

# The current feature
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_train_reviews)
print(train_data_features)

# Convert the result to an array
train_data_features = train_data_features.toarray()

# Initialize a Random Forest classifier with 100 trees
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100) 

# Fit the forest to the training set, using the bag of words as 
# features and the customers as the response variable

forest = forest.fit(train_data_features, train["customers"] )
```

I have tried to use `hstack` to join the arrays but it did not seem like that was the right way.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean when you say hstack didn't seem like the right way. Your goal is to have a matrix of features, where most of the features are counts from your text, and one column is the day of the week. Why doesn't that seem like the right way to you?

Comment: `hstack` should be the right way in your case because you want to concatenate the arrays along the 1-axis, i. e. row-wise. If you do that, you will have an additional feature column `DayOfWeek` in your feature matrix that you may well fit your `RFC` with.

Comment: It may be that I have implemented it wrong - hstack was giving me errors - nupy.hstack:
train_data_features = np.hstack(train_data_features,train_day) gives me this error: 
hstack() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
And scipy.sparse.hstack gives:  ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
Which I've been trying to find a solution for but not getting very far

Comment: Read this, may be you will find something useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783251/growing-matrices-columnwise-in-numpy

Comment: Ok resolved this issue with this:
    train_day=np.asarray(train["day"])
    train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_train_reviews)
    train_data_features = np.hstack([train_data_features,train_day])